# FBSDKGraphRequest not working

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have been trying to make Facebook SDK work on IOS swift, last few days. I am able to get the login working but I could not get profile information. The code is below.
    enter code here

```
func fetchProfile()
{
    print("Inside fetchProfile()")
    let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, name, email, picture"]
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)!
    print("before fetch")

    request.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        else
        {
            print(result)

        }
    }
    )
}
```

I debugged the code, I see the function request.start() is called and returns immediately without printing anything. No errors but no output. Not sure what is going on.. I browsed the web for the solution but to no avail.

My AppDeligate has this code

```
enter code here
func application(application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)!
```

Try passing nil as a parameter and see what the request returns. The user might not have granted permissions or you might have written it wrong.
I saw no replies so I'm trying my best to help you.
Let me know if it doesn't work.